# writing lines to file

Tags: python, string, file, text

so,I have a program that lets the users to input medicine,name,cost,serialnumber,etc...Now, i have a menu,where 1. option is to write in the new medicine. When i choose 2 it should list me all the medicine in a table. I created a function for writing to a txt file,but it wont allow me to write multiple lines. So,when I run the program and I write my first medicine,then I want to add another,it just replaces the first one. Here is the code:

for function:

```
def upisLekova(speclekovi):
    lek = open("lekovi.txt", "w")
    lekovistring = str(speclekovi)
    lek.writelines(lekovistring)
    lek.close()
```

and for the option 1:

```
 if opcija == "1":
         fabrickinazivleka = input("Unesite fabricki naziv leka:\n")
         gennazivleka=input("Unesite genericki naziv leka:\n")
         kolicinaleka = input("Unesite kolicinu lekova:\n")
         cenaleka = input("Unesite cenu leka:\n")
         serijskibrojleka = input("Unesite serijski broj leka:\n")
         fabrickinazivleka = str(fabrickinazivleka)
         gennazivleka = str(gennazivleka)
         kolicinaleka = str(kolicinaleka)
         cenaleka = str(cenaleka)
         serijskibrojleka = str(serijskibrojleka)
         ceolek = fabrickinazivleka + "|" + gennazivleka + "|" + kolicinaleka + "|" + cenaleka + "|" + serijskibrojleka
         upisLekova(ceolek)
         meniMenadzer()
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
`lek = open("lekovi.txt", "a")`